# Connected apps in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, oauth2, connected-apps

Can someone explain the connected apps concept with a basic example or provide me some links where I can find them? I need to connect to another salesforce org from my dev org and retrieve all the classes of the other org and display the list in a  visualforce page in my dev org.

Answer (score 1):

A "Connected App" is an application that can connect to salesforce.com over Identity and Data APIs. Connected Apps use the standard OAuth 2.0 protocol to authenticate, provide Single Sign-On, and acquire access tokens for use with Salesforce APIs.

The information you enter to [**create a connected app**](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_create.htm&language=en_US&type=0) is divided into these parts:

1. Basic Information
2. API (Enable OAuth Settings)
3. Web App Settings
4. Custom Connected App Handler
5. Mobile App Settings
6. Canvas App Settings

So when you want to integrate your app with other Salesforce org you will use OAuth, saving your app gives you two new values that the app uses to communicate with Salesforce.

**Consumer Key:** A value used by the consumer to identify itself to Salesforce. Referred to as client_id in OAuth 2.0.

**Consumer Secret:** A secret used by the consumer to establish ownership of the consumer key. Referred to as client_secret in OAuth 2.0.

This is exactly same when you integrate any API (Twitter, facebook)

Once you get these values you need to follow below steps

1. Get access token from ("https://yourInstance.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token")
2. Call Salesforce API using access token received in step 1.

You can read more about API integration from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart.htm